# Is it possible for Sailsjs to serve up a log file that gets updated by the Sailsjs app?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am working on logging for my SailsJs web app and I have encountered a problem with the log file. The logging works however, when I try to consume it with a frontend, the log file is old because the sails app needs to refresh.

Is there a work around?

Is there a way to maybe serve up the log file in the public folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my own problem.

I installed grunt:

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

and ran grunt while my SailsJs server was running and the log was updated in the public folder.

Then I looked more on the SailsJs website and saw

http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets/disabling-grunt

Although I didn't need to disable it, I noticed this piece:

From http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets/disabling-grunt

NOTE:
When removing the grunt hook above you must also specify the following in .sailsrc in order for your assets to be served, otherwise all assets will return a 404.

`{
    "paths": {
        "public": "assets"
    }
}`

So I added that to my .sailsrc and did a `sails lift` to restart the server. Now the logfile is written to and served up updated everytime there is a change to it.